# Why does setting an app to "All Desktops" make it always show up in the foreground?

Tags: macos, spaces

I use two Spaces on my computer and set up a few apps (note taking, task manager) to show up in "All Desktops".

Although I'm running Ventura, I've seen this behavior for years: when I switch from one desktop to the next, one of the "All Desktops" apps always appear on the foreground for a fraction of a second, before vanishing to the background. If the app was already in the foreground on one Space, it tends to stay there if I move away and back, but this isn't consistently so. But the "flashing" of the "All Desktops" app when I switch Spaces is extremely irritating.

Here's a [short video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQYJG.jpg) illustrating the problem.

Any ideas on how to address this?

Comment: It should only come to the front under those circumstances if the last time that specific Space was moved away from, it was at the front; or if there is no other app on that Space. Could you confirm it's not obeying that 'rule'? I can't repro the brief flash to the front, but I don't have any Mac here on Ventura yet.

Comment: Hi @Tetsujin, I expect the same behavior you describe, but that's not what I see. I added a short video illustrating the problem. If I put the "All Desktops" app in the background, move away and then move back, I see it in the foreground briefly.

Comment: mhm, OK. Might be a Ventura 'change' that I can't test, sorry.

Comment: Hi @Tetsujin, this is definitely something I've seen pre Ventura. Interesting you can't reproduce. What are you running?

Comment: I can see it on Monterey, if I don't blink, if it would arrive behind another Window. On Mojave I don's see it at all. My only 'all spaces' app actually is set to never be behind anything else, as I always want to see it - hence the 'all spaces' flag, so it's not something I would ever normally notice.

Comment: Thanks for this feedback. Out of curiosity, how do you keep that app above all other windows at all times? I didn't think there was a setting for that...

Comment: There isn't, as far as I'm aware [other than specific apps with that function - VLC can do it, though i don't know of any others off-hand]. I do it by simply keeping that area free on all Spaces. I have two 27" screens, so that's not too tough. :)

Comment: Having enough real state is a good solution!

Comment: ;) Aways. I've been used to two large displays since the mid 90s. Without them I feel hemmed-in… trapped… a prisoner in my own castle. A laptop is like a cage ;))